# $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ equivalence of categories + $\mathcal{C}$ complete implies $\mathcal{D}$ complete.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, adjoint-functors

Let $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be an equivalence of categories where $\mathcal{C}$ is a complete category, i.e. any functor $F: I \to \mathcal{C}$ with $I$ small admits a limit.

I'm trying to understand a proof that claims that $\mathcal{D}$ is complete as well.

The proof uses the following result:

> Suppose $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}, G : \mathcal{D} \to
>  \mathcal{C}$ are functors such that $F$ is a left adjoint of $G$. Then
>   $F$ preserves small colimits while $G$ preserves small limits.

The proof I read goes as follows:

> The functor $F$ admits both a left and a right adjoint (this is proven
>   earlier). From the above proposition the result immediately follows.

I'm not sure how exactly this follows. I tried to argue in the following way:

Let $H: I \to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor with $I$ a small category. We show $H$ admits a limit.

Consider a right adjoint $G$ for $F$. Then $G$ preserves limits. Maybe I can use that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which definition of equivalence of categories are you using? Admits an adjoint inverse equivalence? Admits a not-necessarily-adjoint inverse equivalence? Fully faithful and essentially surjective?

Comment: fully faithful ess surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be an inverse equivalence. Let $H:I\to \mathcal{D}$ be a diagram. Then $GH : I\to \mathcal{C}$ admits a limit, $L$, and $FGH \cong H$ has limit $FL$ because $F$ admits a left adjoint, and therefore preserves limits.